# Blank Bokeh plot when reading data from dataframe and using time on x-axis

Tags: pandas, bokeh

I am unable to display plot using Bokeh. I am reading the data from dataframe. Here's a snippet of my Python code.

I am new to Bokeh. I tried following some of the examples from the User Guide. I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong here. Please advise.

```py
import datetime
import pandas
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
PATH_TO_CSV = "Sample_Data.csv"

output_notebook()
data = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV, index_col=False)
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line('timestamp', 'event_msg', source=source)
show(p)
```

Here's sample .csv

```
event_msg,timestamp
Created,2019-03-02 13:19:44.164562-0700
Created,2019-03-02 13:20:32.212323-0700
Created,2019-03-02 13:20:56.582761-0700
Modified,2019-03-02 13:21:48.021752-0700
Deleted,2019-03-02 13:22:16.938382-0700
Modified,2019-03-02 13:22:22.139714-0700
Permission changed,2019-03-02 13:24:20.195975-0700
Deleted,2019-03-02 13:33:53.049900-0700
Modified,2019-03-02 13:33:56.266113-0700
Deleted,2019-03-02 13:33:59.757584-0700
```

I am seeing completely blank plot. Ideally, I am interested in plotting different line plots based on the event messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your time like this:

```
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])
```

So your code should look like (tested with Bokeh v1.1.0):

```
import os
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
PATH_TO_CSV = "Sample_Data.csv"

output_notebook()

data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), PATH_TO_CSV), index_col = False)
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
p = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400, x_axis_type = "datetime", y_range = data['event_msg'].unique())
p.line('timestamp', 'event_msg', source = source)
show(p)
```

Result:

[image]